# Create climate diagram in R with temperature and precipitation

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this

| Month | Year | Temperature | Precipitation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | 2 | 30 |
| 2 | 2019 | 1 | 40 |
| 3 | 2019 | 7 | 50 |
| 4 | 2019 | 10 | 60 |
| 5 | 2019 | 12 | 60 |
| 6 | 2019 | 18 | 70 |
| 7 | 2019 | 20 | 80 |
| 8 | 2019 | 19 | 90 |
| 9 | 2019 | 17 | 80 |
| 10 | 2019 | 10 | 50 |
| 11 | 2019 | 9 | 40 |
| 12 | 2019 | 8 | 40 |
| 1 | 2018 | 4 | 10 |
| 2 | 2018 | 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 2018 | 7 | 70 |
| 4 | 2018 | 12 | 30 |
| 5 | 2018 | 16 | 30 |
| 6 | 2018 | 20 | 20 |
| 7 | 2018 | 24 | 20 |
| 8 | 2018 | 22 | 40 |
| 9 | 2018 | 19 | 40 |
| 10 | 2018 | 13 | 50 |
| 11 | 2018 | 11 | 20 |
| 12 | 2018 | 9 | 10 |

I would like to create a climate table like [image]

I gave that code, but i struggling

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= Month, y=Precipitation )) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")  +
      scale_x_discrete(limits = month.name) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) + ggplot(df, aes(x= Month, y=Temperature )) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")  +
      scale_x_discrete(limits = month.name) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

But error code

```
argument not used
```

But the temperature is not coming? I try everything but all wrong. How can I code that, that the mean Month Temperature and mean Precipitation is shown as a climate diagram? I also had problems with adding a title.

Comment: Maybe this website https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/berryFunctions/html/climateGraph.html would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this, were you use a `geom_bar` for Precipitation and `geom_line` for Temperature with two y-axis and a `facet_wrap` for both years like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x= Month)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y= Precipitation/4, fill = "Precipitation"), stat="identity")  +
  geom_line(aes(y = Temperature, color = "Temperature")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Temperature)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = month.name) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expression("Average Monthly Temperature " ( degree*C)), 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 4, name = "Monthly Precipitation (mm)")
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual("", values = c("Temperature" = "black")) +
  scale_fill_manual("", values = "orange") +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1),
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  facet_wrap(~Year)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Mean temperatur**

For the mean temperature per month, you could first `group_by` month and calculate the `mean` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate(mean_Temp = mean(Temperature)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= Month)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y= Precipitation/4, fill = "Precipitation"), stat="identity")  +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_Temp, color = "Temperature")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean_Temp)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = month.name) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expression("Average Monthly Temperature " ( degree*C)), 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 4, name = "Monthly Precipitation (mm)")
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual("", values = c("Temperature" = "black")) +
  scale_fill_manual("", values = "orange") +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: yes, but how can I code that the mean of 2018 and 2019 come in to one plot?

Comment: Can I plot the average of 2018 and 2019?

Comment: the code is very useful

Comment: Should I just put y=mean(Precipitation)?

Comment: @PatMadriz, I added some code at bottom of my answer. You could first `group_by` and calculate the mean to combine the years. Is that what you want?

Comment: Be aware of the 1:2 scaling between the temperature and precipitation ticks on the y-axes, c.f. e.g. [here](http://www.klima-der-erde.de/grafiken/stockholm.gif).

Comment: @Quinten, How can you fix the points for the temperature. I also would like to create a diagram, but without point. Could you please help me?

Comment: Hi @JaimeGilmartin, you can remove the geom_point() code line. This removes the points.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but one more option: This basic code may be adapted in any direction:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
coeff=5

df %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy(paste(1, Month, Year))) %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Precipitation)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_line(aes(y = Temperature*coeff), color = "orange", size=1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Temperature*coeff), color = "orange", size=2.5)+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",
               date_labels = "%B %y")+
  scale_y_continuous("Precipitation", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./coeff, name = "Temperature")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)+
  labs(x="")+
  ggtitle("Climatogram XXX")+
  theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "orange"), 
      axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "orange"),
      axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "orange"), 
      axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "orange"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)
      )
```

[image]
**Code for Average:**

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
coeff=5

df %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy(paste(1, Month, Year))) %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  mutate(mean_temp = mean(Temperature),
         mean_precip = mean(Precipitation)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = mean_precip)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_temp*coeff), color = "orange", size=1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean_temp*coeff), color = "orange", size=2.5)+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",
               date_labels = "%B %y")+
  scale_y_continuous("Average \n Precipitation", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./coeff, name = "Average \n Temperature")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)+
  labs(x="")+
  ggtitle("Climatogram XXX")
  theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "orange"), 
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "orange"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "orange"), 
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "orange"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
  ) +
  ggtitle("Climatogram for Oslo (1961-1990)")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice plot! Create to combine the years in one. Warum sind die Monate auf Deutsch actually?

Comment: Do you know how can I create the temperature without the points?

Comment: Just remove `geom_point(aes(y = mean_temp*coeff), color = "orange", size=2.5)+`